# Search for wild card and string in variable array

Tags: arrays, regex, python-2.7

** Problem ** I'm trying to search line by line through files I've added to an array filename and print any strings containing filename.mxf using a wildcard such as *.mxf. Lines in the files would be \E:\AVMedia\filename.mxf. I want to list just filename.mxf in variable (matching).

```
## opens files in array ##

  print name #debug#
  file = open(os.path.join(path,filename), 'r')
  #print file.read()

## search for all strings containing .mxf from array ##

## create regular expression ##

pattern = "(*.mxf)"

matching = [s for s in rasp if re.match(pattern, '\')]
print matching
```

Comment: What do you mean by `re.match('?',pattern)`? `pattern` should be the first argument and `'?'` is an invalid regex pattern. It would be of great help if you provide the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the example down to meet MCVE. I thought it might be important as to how the array was created. I'm unsure how to use re.match to search for *.mxf in each line and display only filename.mxf and not \E:\AVMedia\filename.mxf

Comment: Try [`pattern = r"[^\s\\]+\.mxf\b"` with `re.findall`](https://ideone.com/Vu1X9u).

Comment: Thanks, after the pattern variable has been made, how would I apply this to the array (rasp) to print the results?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do with those results. Add a relevant tag if that is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of different issues with your attempt:

1. Wildcard (or `glob`) patterns are not the same as regular expressions.

   In a regular expression, `*` matches 0 or more of the previous item in the expression.  If `*` appears at the beginning of an expression (or subexpression, as in a parenthesized subexpression or the alternation `|` operator separating multiple subexpressions), then it has no special meaning and just matches a `*` character.

   ```
   pattern = "(*.mxf)"
   ```

   is therefore a regular expression that has a parenthesized subexpression that matches the literal string `*.mxf`.  You can use `.*` instead of `*` to match any number of any non-newline characters, or `[^/]*` to match any number of non-path-separator characters.
2. `re.match(pattern, '\')` is illegal (the `\` escapes the following `'` and so you end up with an unterminated string).
3. Even if you fix it to `re.match(patterh, '\\')`, you're matching your pattern against the fixed string `\` each time.  I assume what you actually want is

   ```
   matching = [s for s in rasp if re.match(pattern, s)]
   ```

   in order to return a list of each item in `rasp` that matches the regular expression in `pattern`.

Your best solution is perhaps to make your pattern a true filename glob pattern (`pattern = "*.mxf"`) and use python's `fnmatch` pattern checker instead:

```
import fnmatch
import os.path
pattern = "*.mxf"
matching = [os.path.basename(s) for s in rasp if fnmatch.fnmatch(s, pattern)]
print matching
```

Comment: Thanks you J earls. Especially for the explanation, very big help. I'll mark this one as correct however I'm not sure how to use this with my current array, on the `print matching` I get an output of only `[]`. Could you take a look at how I've made the array? my understanding is still very limited.

Comment: better yet, ask a new question with your updated code, since this is a new question :)